# cloudflare js worker allow list of countries and block the rest

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, worker, cloudflare-workers

i'm trying to adjust the following code to be like allow if the country in the list and block if not  ,  the current code does the oppiste block if the country in the list and allow if not

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(blockCountries(event.request))
})

//Add countries to this Set to block them
const countries = new Set([  
  "US", // United States
  "SG", // Singapore 
  "BR"  // Brazil
])

async function blockCountries(request) {
  // Get country value from request headers
  let country = request.headers.get('cf-ipcountry')

  // Find out if country is on the block list
  let countryBlocked = countries.has(country)

  // If it's on the blocked list, give back a 403
  if (countryBlocked){
    return new Response("This page not available in your country",
        { status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden" })
  }

  // Catch-all return of the original response
  return await fetch(request)
}
```

any tips to adjust this

Answer (score 0):

In order to make that change, you can change this:

```js
let countryBlocked = countries.has(country)
```

to this: (note the exclamation mark)

```js
let countryBlocked = !countries.has(country)
```

The exclamation mark is the `NOT` operator. So this change will set `countryBlocked` to `true` if the country for this request is NOT in the set of allowed countries.

One thing to be aware of is that if the country is not known for a given request, [it may show up as "XX"](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-).

Here's the full code with that change and updated comments to reflect the new behavior:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(blockCountries(event.request))
})

// Add countries to this Set to allow them
const countries = new Set([  
  "US", // United States
  "SG", // Singapore 
  "BR"  // Brazil
])

async function blockCountries(request) {
  // Get country value from request headers
  let country = request.headers.get('cf-ipcountry')

  // Check if country is on the allowed list
  let countryBlocked = !countries.has(country)

  // If it's not on the allowed list, give back a 403
  if (countryBlocked){
    return new Response("This page not available in your country",
        { status: 403, statusText: "Forbidden" })
  }

  // Catch-all return of the original response
  return await fetch(request)
}
```